# How to use AWS Java SDK to connect Complaint S3 Service?

Tags: java, scala, amazon-s3, openstack, openstack-swift

I am trying to implement a simple Java/Scala client to connect to the S3 Service which provided by the OpenStack Swift(it supports S3 API).
However the codes seems not working when I am using AWS Java SDK 1.11.176.
Could anyone share me some lights?

Thanks!

```
def listBuckets(config: Config, bucketName: String): Unit = {
    val accessKey = "85eb40dxxxxx"
    val secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    val endPoint = "https://v01.my.company.net:8080"
    val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    val clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfig.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
    val client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
       .withCredentials(newAWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
       .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig)
       .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
       .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(endPoint, "us-east-1"))
       .build();
    System.out.println(client.listBuckets())
}
```

Error is like this:

> null (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null)
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: null (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1587)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1029)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:741)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:665)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:647)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:511)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4227)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4174)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4168)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:918)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:924)

Comment: Openstack Swift does not Support S3 API by default. Are you sure this support is enabled?

Comment: @NelsonMarcos, thanks for you reply. Yes, I can use the 3pp tool s3cmd to access the Swift S3API correctly. The environment was set up by Mirantis.

Comment: have you tried to force v2 signing?

Comment: @khc, could you explain a little more detail? there are too many parameters. thanks!

Comment: Looks like my S3 SDK doesn't have V2 Type.         // Register the standard signer types.
        SIGNERS.put(QUERY_STRING_SIGNER, QueryStringSigner.class);
        SIGNERS.put(VERSION_THREE_SIGNER, AWS3Signer.class);
        SIGNERS.put(VERSION_FOUR_SIGNER, AWS4Signer.class);
        SIGNERS.put(NO_OP_SIGNER, NoOpSigner.class);

Comment: I downgrade the AWS S3 SDK from 1.11.176 to 1.10.77 and it works. What is the different between 1.11 and 1.10?

Comment: The newer sdk defaults to v4 signing: https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Java/9979983567247718 . Did using AWS3Signer.class work?

Comment: Thanks @khc, I switched to AWS3Signer yesterday and it doesn't throw exception when list buckets, however no buckets are listed. Create bucket is not working as well when using AWS3Signer. I will try it again today.